# retrieve data from multiple multi select dropdown with same name in one form

Tags: php, html

I am trying to handle multiple `multi select` boxes/dropdown with same name on one page and on one form. They have the same name because these dropdown/boxes are adding dynamically. My question is how to retrieve data of each select box individually. Its showing the result like this:

```
Array(
        [0] => M
        [1] => T
        [2] => W 
 )
```

But I want the result like this

```
  Array
  (
     [0] => Array(
               [0] => M
               [2] => T
             )
     [1] => Array(
               [0] => W
             )
  )
```

I am trying this code:

```
  <td class="v-align-middle semi-bold sorting_1">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-default form-group-default-select2 full-width days" id="111">
                                    <label>SELECT DAYS</label>
                                    <select id="dw" name="days[]" class="full-width select2-offscreen" data-init-plugin="select2" multiple="" tabindex="-1">
                                        <option value="M">Monday</option>
                                        <option value="T">Tuesday</option>
                                        <option value="W">Wednesday</option>
                                        <option value="Th">Thursday</option>
                                        <option value="F">Friday</option>
                                        <option value="Sa">Saturday</option>
                                        <option value="Su">Sunday</option>
                                    </select>

                            </div> <br/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
```

This is the code I am using to clone my table:

```
   $('.add-ins').on('click', function(){
     var selfId = $(this).attr('id');
     var tId = $(this).parent().parent().find('table').attr('id');
     var lastId = $('.timings#'+tId+' tbody tr:visible:last').attr('id');
     lastId++;
     $('select').select2('destroy'); /* destroy select2 from select tag and then clone it */          
    var clonerow = $('.timings#'+tId+' tbody tr:visible:last').clone(true, true).attr('id', lastId);
    clonerow.appendTo('.timings#'+tId+' tbody');
    $('select').select2(); /* enable Select2 on the select elements */
});
```

PHP Code:

```
  $days = $_POST['days'];
  foreach($days as $value){
       echo $value; 
       foreach($value as $week){ 
     echo  $week; 
     }
  }
```

Or simply this:

```
   print_r($days);
```

Kindly, help me in this regard. If there is any other solution like using different name for each select box then kindly tell me how to post them using php `$_POST` as I can not figure out how many multiselect boxes will be added by the user.

Your suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards

Comment: Please show your `HTML` code so that we can check

Comment: I have added the html in my question, kindly check it.

Comment: If dynamicly added, can you show the code that generates it?

Comment: Yes, I have added jquery code that clone the table. Kindly, check it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please code in html like

```
<select id="dw" name="days[0][]" class="full-width select2-offscreen" data-init-plugin="select2" multiple="" tabindex="-1">
 <option value="M">Monday</option>
 <option value="T">Tuesday</option>
 <option value="W">Wednesday</option>
 <option value="Th">Thursday</option>
 <option value="F">Friday</option>
 <option value="Sa">Saturday</option>
 <option value="Su">Sunday</option>
</select>

<select id="dw" name="days[1][]" class="full-width select2-offscreen" data-init-plugin="select2" multiple="" tabindex="-1">
 <option value="M">Monday</option>
 <option value="T">Tuesday</option>
 <option value="W">Wednesday</option>
 <option value="Th">Thursday</option>
 <option value="F">Friday</option>
 <option value="Sa">Saturday</option>
 <option value="Su">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yes, it works. That's great. You saved my day. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

You should use like following way:

```
1:
<select id="dw" name="days[0][]" >
    <option value="M">Monday</option>
</select>

2:
<select id="dw" name="days[1][]" >
    <option value="M">Monday</option>
</select>
```

If you are inserting select box using `javascript` then take variable to set `0/1/2...` for `name` of select.

POST data:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array(
            [0] => M
            [1] => T
          )
   [1] => Array(
            [0] => W
          )
)
```